# AWS Amplify Graphql Schema, how to filter own data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

consider for example a Comment type as discribed below:

```
type Comment @model  @auth(rules: [
  { allow: public, operations: [read]}
  { allow: owner }
]) {
id: ID!
text: String!
}
```

my question is how can an owner filter his own comments, is there any implicit relation that we can use between Apmlify Auth & Amplify api , otherwise I will add a new field in the schema

```
cognitoID @index(name:'byCognitoID', queryField: "commentByCognitoID")
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create the field to have the relationship:

```
type Comment @model  @auth(rules: [
   { allow: owner }
   { allow: public, operations: [read]}
]) {
id: ID!
text: String!
owner: String @index(name: "commentsByOwner", queryField: "commentsByOwner")
}
```

Then use:

```
amplify push
```

Now it will create your queries and you should see one named commentsByOwner.

I realize this is still creating a new property in your schema, but I believe this is the only way to do this for now without removing the public auth rule.

https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/auth/#field-level-authorization

Answer (score 0):

The new way V2 is to use the "ownerField" attribute as shown below.

```
type Recipe 
@model 
@auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField:"author" }]) 
{
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  ingredients: [String]!
  instructions: [String]!
  author: String
}
```

An example is shown here https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/graphqlapi/customize-authorization-rules/#per-user--owner-based-data-access

Comment: If you use this as a way to query by owner/author, you will have to pass the ownerID::username (if using username as the auth type) when creating a new item. I currently dont see this as a problem, for my use case, but open to hearing if anyone sees any issues.